# googleMap.getMyLocation(); cannot get current location

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps-api-2

i want to make a program to calculate the distance between some places to my current location, but my googleMap.getMyLocation(); doesnt work properly.

```
googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);   
googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
mylocation = googleMap.getMyLocation();
direction = new GMapV2Direction();

LatLng from, to;
from = new LatLng(-7.26071409, 112.80674726);
for(int i=0; i<lat.length; i++){    
    to = new LatLng(lat[i], lon[i]);
    doc = direksi.getDocument(from, to, GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING);
    distance[i] = (double)direction.getDistanceValue(doc) / 1000;
}
```

i saved the latitude and longitude of some places in lat[] and lon[].
LatLng 'from' is mylocation and 'to' is my destination places.
the problem appear when i change

```
from = new LatLng(-7.26071409, 112.80674726);
to
from = new LatLng(mylocation.getLatitude(), mylocation.getLongitude());
```

i want to do the calculation without opening the googlemaps. the google maps will appear when i touch the map button as pop up window. so the calculation will happen without opening googlemap

please help me

Comment: getMyLocation(), [this method is deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html). use LocationClient instead.

Comment: are you using google map v2?

Comment: @Alex i dont know how to use LocationClient. can you elaborate?

Comment: @Android yes i'm using google map v2 api

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this...I hope this will be help to you

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
        getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager
        .getBestProvider(criteria, false));
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
```

Comment: no it does not, since you don't even check getBestProvider and getLastKnownLocation to get null!

Answer (score 12):

This is my code for you, I hope this help you... edit it if you think, it isn't with correct sintaxis...

This work for android 4.x and 5.x and 6.x,  I not test this in android 7

```
//I use this like global var to edit or get informacion about google map
GoogleMap gMap;

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    gMap = googleMap;

if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Activity_Map.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Activity_Map.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Activity_Map.this,new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
                    }else{
                        if(!gMap.isMyLocationEnabled())
                            gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                        Location myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                        if (myLocation == null) {
                            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
                            String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
                            myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                        }

                        if(myLocation!=null){
                            LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude());
                            gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 14), 1500, null);
                        }
                    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

`getMyLocation()` => [this method is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#getMyLocation()). You need to use `LocationClient` instead.

You can find informations about `LocationClient` and how to get current location [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#GetLocation)